# Right Align Text File

Tags: python

Trying to right align the 2nd set of strings. What are some other methods that I could use so that the characters in the first string doesn't affect the format of the second string?

This is what I have so far.

count = 0
for line in inputFile:

%(total) + "\n")

```
    for lis)
```

Comment: What does the input data look like?

Comment: @gmds The same as the Result, but bunch of numbers that needed to be add in the 3rd column,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply string formatting to right justify like this:

```
my_list = ['A12345678', "Adams, John", 14.98]
print("{0} {1:>20} {2:}".format(my_list[0], my_list[1], my_list[2]))
```

Where the `{0}`, `{1}`, and `{2}` specify position of the arguments, and the `:>20` denotes that you want to ensure a length of 20 characters (right justified) for that item.

Output:

```
A12345678          Adams, John 14.98
```

So just decide how many characters you expect to be printing at max and then substitute that number for the `20` in my code!

For more string formatting methods for both the `%` and `.format()` methods check out https://pyformat.info/